# C# VSTO Word Addin - need to save the table and retrieving it back to word document

Tags: c#, sql, ms-word, range, vsto

I was able to read a text and write it back to a word document.

I have a table with data. I have to read the entire table object and  save it to the database, then retrieve the table back to word document whenever needed.

Here is the code for the text content. I need the same for Table object.

```
private string Get(Word.Range range)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.Clear();
    if (range.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        rtb = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        range.Select();
        oWord.Selection.Copy();
        rtb.Rtf = (string)System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Rtf); ;
        System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.Clear();
        return rtb.Rtf.Remove(rtb.Rtf.LastIndexOf("\\pard"), 5);
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: i need to save the entrie table object with design into database and retrieve the table object back to word whenever needed with design.. The datatype of the SQL table field is nvarchar(Max). Kindly help me out..

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up the exact range as defined in Word using WordOpenXML and restoring it with InsertXML.

Read:

```
string txt = range.WordOpenXML();
```

Save txt to your database.

Write back

```
range.InsertXML(txt);
```

Where txt was pulled from your database.

So, in theory you could backup and restore your complete document using:

```
ActiveDocument.Content.WordOpenXML();
```